# Dual wifi router setup

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ethernet, switch

Can I use a gigabit ethernet switch plugged into my cable modem and then plug two different wifi routers into the switch.  I want to use my new high speed router to always go through my VPN and my old slower speed router to connect normally.

thanks

Comment: Yes you can do that. Have you already configured the new high speed router with the vpn ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, provided they are Ethernet routers and the VPN is configured on the router. You will also want to make sure the routers are on different channels (at least 3 channels apart), as I'm guessing you want to switch connections based on SSID ?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use a gigabit ethernet switch plugged into my cable modem and
>   then plug two different wifi routers into the switch. I want to use my
>   new high speed router to always go through my VPN and my old slower
>   speed router to connect normally.

The answer is: "Maybe".

If your ISP is providing a device that is a cable modem, a NAT firewall, and a router (this is common), and if you have been assigned only one routable (public) IP address (this is often the case), then you can do this, but you may need to configure the ISP equipment to forward connections to your high speed router.

If your ISP is only providing a bare modem, and only one routable (public) IP address, the configuration you describe might be problematic.

If your ISP is providing a bare modem and more than one routable (public) IP address, then you're golden.  Give one IP to each of your routers.